# Will the API support the chat system?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, write-access, chat

Having read through come of the questions on here it's my understanding that v 1.0 of the API is for read-only access to real-time data, pretty much what's available in the data dump. Write support is planned for version 2.0. My question is, will version 2.0, or some future version after that, have a means to access [the chat system](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)? Specifically, what I'm looking for is a way for Stack Apps to authenticate as a user and post messages to a Stack Exchange chat room. Is such functionality planned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its too early to call this, as the chat system is still evolving.

However, exposing the inbox *is* planned and since some chat events are published to the inbox there will be at least some exposure of chat events.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I think I've found another way to do XMPP write support in the meantime :-)

Comment: Now it's more than two years later, how about it? Does API v2.1 include chat access?

Comment: In the meantime, the community has stepped up to the plate: http://stackapps.com/a/7248/18

Comment: 7 years later??

Comment: @programmer5000, and even 8 years later :(