# Is there a way to programmatically access chat?

Tags: support, chat

I'm thinking about starting a project where I'd like to have access to the "chat" feature of the stack exchange sites.  I saw this project: [*IRC access for the chat?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/59760/irc-access-for-the-chat)

But I don't believe that it works with the current revision of the chat system.

API access is also requested in [Will the API support the chat system?](https://stackapps.com/questions/1798/will-the-api-support-the-chat-system).

But it appears that the feature has been deferred.

In the meantime, what ways do I have with interacting with the chat features of the network?
It looks like there might be a "starred comment" RSS feed, (EG: `chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/ROOM_NUM`) but is that the only interaction currently possible?

Answer (score 3):

There is no official API provided for the chat network. As Marc's answer mentions, there are a number of community efforts to bridge the gap:

#### Go

- [go-sechat](https://stackapps.com/questions/7245/go-sechat-go-package-for-interacting-with-the-stack-exchange-chat-network)

#### JavaScript

- [ChatBot](https://stackapps.com/questions/3775/chatbot-a-bot-for-the-chat)
- [ChatExchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/6527/chatexchange-it-is-an-api-for-chat)
- [ThirdPlace](https://stackapps.com/questions/3033/thirdplace-javascript-chat-library)
- [ArtOfChatbot](https://stackapps.com/questions/6274/artofchatbot-chat-api-a-customisable-chatbot)
- [SO-ChatBot Boilerplate](https://github.com/jbis9051/SO-ChatBot) - Remove the plugins and you have a boilerplate where you can create your own bot. Documentation is in the `./docs` folder

#### Python

- [ChatExchange](https://github.com/Manishearth/ChatExchange)
- [sechat](https://github.com/GingerIndustries/sechat)

#### Rebol

- [RebolBot](https://stackapps.com/questions/3960/rebolbot-a-chat-bot-for-the-chat-rooms)

<sub>If you are the author of a library / package for chat, feel free to edit this answer and add a link to yours.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

and what exactly would you have? you are correct in that there is no *officially supported* API available for chat. Some fairly successful efforts  have been made by the community (unrelated to SE) to reverse engineer the API that chat uses; but that is not the same thing as a supported and documented API.

AFAIK there are no active plans to implement a direct API for this. As already noted by Jeff, if we *did* do this, it probably wouldn't fit into *quite* the same API *anyway* (for reasons such as: data-centre proximity).

Comment: You can find an example of such an app [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/2444/flackbot-making-conversation-in-the-chat-rooms).

Comment: I'd like to be able to read (and ideally write) to the chat system from some alternative interface.  I can certainly attempt to reverse engineer it, and if that's what others have done (and been successful with/avoided violating any usage restrictions) then I can go that route.  Something supported that isn't likely to change on a whim and break my stuff, whether it's part of this API or that API would be nice though.

Comment: @agent86 "read (and ideally write)" is pretty vague. What **exactly** do you want to do. Just to help me understand. Read existing transcripts? Query against new changes to active chats (which would typically be much more frequent / high usage)?

Comment: I haven't completely decided yet, so apologies for the vagueness.  One idea I'm having is a command-line driven ncurses chat client, for times when I can't have a full-blown browser running.  Another thing I'm considering is some sort of IRC 'bot that is capable of generating statistics or perhaps filtering/analyzing the chat stream.  For this, the RSS of starred chat entries might be enough.  I haven't completely scoped everything because I don't know what's fully possible.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison, your app probably does quite a bit of the things I'm interested in, but I note that it's not open source.  Are there any examples of open source projects that have "reverse engineered" the chat system so that I don't need to start from scratch?

Comment: @agent86: For security reasons *part* of it isn't open source. The rest is [here](https://launchpad.net/flackbot).

Comment: @GeorgeEdison, thanks for the link.  I didn't see that in the original question, did I miss it?  If so, my apologies.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison, what functionality is missing from the open source version?

Comment: @agent86: You can find a bit more here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/719394/

Answer (score 2):

There's unofficial collaborative [Chat API Documentation](https://github.com/jbis9051/SO-ChatBot/blob/master/docs/CHAT_API.md) for how everything in chat works.

Its split up into a couple different parts:

- [Authentication](https://github.com/jbis9051/SO-ChatBot/blob/master/docs/CHAT_API.md#authentication)
- [Receiving Events (Messages + other stuff)](https://github.com/jbis9051/SO-ChatBot/blob/master/docs/CHAT_API.md#receiving-events-messages--other-stuff)
- [Sending Events/Messages](https://github.com/jbis9051/SO-ChatBot/blob/master/docs/CHAT_API.md#sending-eventsmessages)
- [User Information](https://github.com/jbis9051/SO-ChatBot/blob/master/docs/CHAT_API.md#user-information)

More information here: [Stack Exchange Chat API Documentation and Bot Boilerplate (finally)](https://stackapps.com/questions/8336/stack-exchange-chat-api-documentation-and-bot-boilerplate-finally)

**Note**: I started the documentation above. Feel free to contribute, add any new information you find, and fix any mistakes. I would like for this to become the main documentation people use :)