# ChatBot, a bot. For the chat

Tags: app, script, chat, chatbot

### About

Lurks in the shadows of the chat. It executes commands at the request of the user, sending messages as the user who runs it.

You can talk to it the [StackOverflow SandBox room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1/sandbox) if you want to play (it goes by the name [Caprica Six](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839506/caprica-six)), start out with `!!listcommands`.

#### How to use (bot runner)

Run `bookmarklet.js` in a chat window. Bam. It's alive! It's using your name! Run, run before it's too late! The `<center>` cannot hold it's  to---

The [README](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-ChatBot/blob/master/README.md) file should contain all you need for running, and if you want to extend the bot with additional awesome, refer to [this page](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-ChatBot/wiki/Plugin-writing) or just hack around. It's not overly complex.

#### How to use (chat user)

See [Interacting with the Bot](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-ChatBot/wiki/Interacting-with-the-bot). Do note that the `!!` prefix pattern is not constant - the bot runner can change it at will.

#### Why you shouldn't use it

It's unstable (I'm a bad maintainer). It forgets stuff (like <strike>learned commands</strike> ([fixed](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-ChatBot/commit/c25447225fa01aaf3a6fca3a3bf949f01cab6cf6)) or nudges) on refresh. It won't work if someone isn't actively acting as its bitch. It makes you its bitch and will probably activate the message-throttler, making you unable to talk, if people are actively using it. oh, it's also buggy.

#### Why you should use it

It's fun, it's awesome, it's easily extendable and it's damn useful. And I'm aware of its condition, so it's in an upwards slope.

#### License

[WTFPL](http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/)

#### Download

Code is available on [github](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-ChatBot/).

Comment: Oh this old question of mine on meta might be of interest: [Are bots specifically allowed or prohibited in Stack Exchange chatrooms?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/116589)

Comment: I like the license the most :)

Comment: I'm trying to run this in Aviation's [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/aviation), but I'm getting `parseMessage invalid` logs every time. Tried using the `master.js` in your GitHub, and also checked out and built. @ rlemon and @ allquixotic haven't been able to help - could you maybe drop me a message when you have 10 minutes, or point me to some docs that might help? Thanks!