# ChatExchange - It is an API for Chat

Tags: library, javascript, chat

### Code Snippet

```
sendMessage('chat.meta.stackexchange.com', 721, 'Hello @Sha', fkey().fkey)

//Sends the message 'Hello @Sha' to Shadow's Den
//Must be run in a chat site, due to @Balpha not wanting CORS in Chat :(
```

### About

It is an API for Chat, made in Javascript

#### License

ChatExchange is released under the [Apache License 2.0](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0).

#### Download

You can download ChatExchange here:
[Compressed Version](http://teamfreehugs.github.io/js/min/ChatExchange.min.js) or [Normal Version](http://teamfreehugs.github.io/js/ChatExchange.js)

### Contact

I can be reached at `eyeballcode@gmail.com`.

### Code

ChatExchange is written in javascript.

The code can be retrieved from here:
http://teamfreehugs.github.io/js/min/ChatExchange.min.js

Comment: Thanks for this simple, easy-to-use chat libary! Please consider adding documentation.