# Stack Exchange Chat API Documentation and Bot Boilerplate (finally)

Tags: app, library, chat, chatbot

## Chat Documentation

**GitHub Link:**

https://github.com/jbis9051/JamesSOBot/blob/master/docs/CHAT_API.md

**Description**:

I know many people have created bots in different languages. Thats why I need your help to contribute to the documentation so we can finally have documentation for how the Stack Exchange Chat works.

I have started with some main information on stuff like obtaining the `fkey` and establishing the WebSocket, but I encourage you to contribute your own findings and correct any inaccuracies!

## Bot - Boilerplate

**GitHub Link**:

https://github.com/jbis9051/SO-ChatBot

**Description**:

I could not find a simple and easy to understand Stack Exchange chat bot API so I decided to create my own. This can be easily used to create your own bot, simply remove the plugins and add your own!

**[Bot Documentation](https://jbis9051.github.io/SO-ChatBot/index.html)**

You can test the bot [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193540/test-my-bot).

Comment: The doc link is dead. The implementation language seems to be Typescript.