# How do I send a message to Stack Exchange Chat using a webhook?

Tags: support, chat, chatbot

Apparently this is off-topic for Meta SE.

---

I have a repository for Utility Bot, a Stack Exchange chatbot I made. GitHub has a feature that allows you to send repository events via a POST request to a URL. How can I do this with Stack Exchange Chat?

Comment: *sigh* This information should really be actually in Q&A pairs here, but it looks like at least a couple of questions and answers point to the documentation [here](https://github.com/jbis9051/JamesSOBot/blob/master/docs/CHAT_API.md#sending-eventsmessages). The questions/answers which point there are at least: "[Stack Exchange Chat API Documentation and Bot Boilerplate (finally)](https://stackapps.com/q/8336/29529)" and [answer to: "Is there a way to programmatically access chat?"](https://stackapps.com/a/8344/29529)